# Reliable close Android Keyboard

Tags: android, android-fragments, keyboard

I experiencing a lot troubles and inconveniences when it comes to the android keyboard (especially when it should go hidden). What i want to do is to hide the keyboard, in a lot of different usecases.

I know there are methods for hiding it via `InputMethodManager` as well as `Window.setSoftInputMode()`, but all the methods are causing the same kind of trouble for me.

The problem is that often when the keyboard is closed it immediately reappears. Sometimes even without having a valid target the input gets directed to. So i wonder why this is happening and how i could prevent that? Is there a reliable method to close the keyboard and keeping it close?

For example currently i have a case where i have a fragment containing some `EditTexts`. On a button click the fragment is hidden and the keyboard dismissed. However a keyboard immediately reappears although `getCurrentFocus()` returns null or a `ListView` which should not trigger a keyboard to show. But the keyboard does not even point to one of the fragments `EditTexts` because if i show the fragment again i have the keyboard but the input just going to nowhere.

Additionally to fixing this, i would really like to know what is going on internally. As far as my experience is concerned unfocusing an element in android means that something else gets focused, which often causes unpredictable results. Especially as this happens implicitly on fragment transaction and therelike.

Comment: have you tried inserting in your manifest.xml under the activity you have the editTexts  "android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden", but that is only if you want not the keyboard to pop up upon the creation of the edit texts

Comment: But that would mean that initially the keyboard does not pop up which is desired.